# How to get an installed program – JDeveloper

Tags: software-installation

I installed Jdeveloper on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS , using the Terminal ( in Next , Next , ... ) as the wizard didn't appear for me.

The Program has been installed but I can't found it to use it !

Comment: Which version, which edition of JDeveloper?

Comment: jdevstudio11117install >> I think it was 12c

Comment: yes , 
I use the " ls " command ... before i install it , it was in white , but now it 's in green 
forgive me , I am a new user that interseted in Linux

Comment: now what ?
what's the monster :D ?

Comment: plz , how can i access the root folder ?

Comment: :D , I am sorry , take ur time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28810/discussion-between-a-b-and-moaaz-elneshawy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Oracle JDeveloper 11g

*Oracle JDeveloper 11g can only start a CLI installer.*

After downloading the bin file, eg. `jdevstudio11117install.bin` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/jdeveloper11117-1917330.html) make it executable via

```
chmod +x jdevstudio11117install.bin
```

1. **Install a i386 library**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
   ```
2. **Now start the installation**

   ```
   ./jdevstudio11117install.bin
   ```

   Per default, the software well be installed in

   ```
   ~/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper
   ```
3. **Start**

   As there is no desktop file installed, you can start via

   ```
   ~/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev
   ```
4. **Create a `desktop` file**

   - Create the file `jdeveloper.desktop`

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/applications/jdeveloper.desktop
     ```

     **Replace `$USER` with your username, the output of `echo $USER`**

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Encoding=UTF-8
     Version=1.0
     Type=Application
     Name=JDeveloper 11g
     Comment=JDeveloper 11g Integrated Development Environment
     Icon=/home/$USER/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/coffee.png
     Exec=/home/$USER/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev
     StartupNotify=true
     StartupWMClass=JDeveloper
     ```

     The icon is very ugly, but I can't find a better icon
5. **Start via your Launcher, type "JDev"**

   The first start takes some time…

   [image]

Comment: what if I want to lock it to Launch Menu ?
It doesn't be locked ! ,, Why ?

Answer (score 1):

### JDev Suite 12c

After downloading the `bin` file, eg `jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) make it executable via

```
chmod +x jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin
```

1. **Now start the installation**

   ```
   ./jdev_suite_121300_linux64.bin
   ```

   [image]
2. **You can change your installation folder here**

   [image]
3. **Start**

   As there is no desktop file installed, you can start via

   ```
   ~/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev
   ```

   the path `~/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/` depends on your settings of <kbd>Installation location</kbd> in step 3
4. **Create a `desktop` file**

   - Create the file `jdeveloper.desktop`

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/applications/jdevsuite.desktop
     ```

     **Replace `$USER` with your username, the output of `echo $USER`**

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Encoding=UTF-8
     Version=1.0
     Type=Application
     Name=JDev Suite 12c
     Comment=JDev Suite 12c Integrated Development Environment
     Icon=/home/$USER/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/coffee.png
     Exec=/home/$USER/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/bin/jdev
     StartupNotify=true
     StartupWMClass=JDevSuite
     ```

     The icon is very ugly, but I can't find a better icon
5. **Start via your Launcher, type "JDev"**

Comment: I get the access on it's folder , and i tried to start the installation but " Permission Denied " !  -------   bash: ./jdevstudio11117install.bin: Permission denied

Comment: I do that 1st ,  then [./jdevstudio11117install.bin] , Permission Denied

Comment: downloading rightnow , 
I will try these steps and i will inform you about the results , 
Thank you MR A.B :) ;)

Comment: Should work, I've done every step itself.

Comment: the problem is , the wizard doesn't appear , 
 just the installation is work on Terminal !! --- [http://i.imgur.com/0CRob91.png?1] _Check_